# Hide Actionbar without menu option

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I wanna hide action bar without hiding menu option.I have used object of action bar to hide it.But from that menu option are also hiding. Help...
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.hide();

Comment: What do you expect? The menu is part of the Toolbar. So when you hide the Toolbar - the menu is gone of course.

Comment: chrjs you are correct. @shivam if you want your option menu only visible - remove title from toolbar & make it transparent not remove/hide toolbar.